# Android: AVD Another "Failed to Allocate Memory: 8" Post

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I've done a lot of searching, and there doesn't appear to be a solution to this other than setting the avd memory down to about 512. I should have no problems running avd's with 1024 or higher ram as my machine is a quadcore xeon with 16 gb of RAM. The solution that is most routinely offered is to open the .ini file for the AVD and put MB after the RAM size declaration. This isn't a solution because the system doesn't recognize that entry with the 'MB' and forces the AVD to run at it's default which is usually either 512 or 256. My question is, am I crazy, or has this problem been going on forever with no viable solution from google? If there is an ACTUAL solution, could someone please post it here.
My system info is as follows:
Windows 7 64bit
Intel Xeon 2.8 GHz
16 GB Ram
Aptana Studio with Eclipse Android Plugins (most recent sdk release, 21 I think)

Comment: Here's an interesting development. If I run the AVD Manager from Explorer in Windows XP compatibility mode I don't get the "Failed to Allocate Memory: 8" error anymore. I get the following: "emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 1024MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 576MB." Then in continues to run instead of failing. This is still ludicrous as I'm only currently running Chrome and Outlook 2010 with 16 GB of RAM. My system says I have haver 12 GB of memory remaining. It seems that the device manager doesn't know how to properly reserve RAM.